# XPages: after a delay, a save action reopens the document

Tags: xpages

A user opens an XPage with a document, no problems. After several minutes of inactivity on the page, s/he saves the page (simple action). The result is that the document is reopened for some reason and then saved. The reopen effectively undoes all modifications applied by the user. In our logs we can see this happening, but we have no explanation.

Our conclusion is that apparently the document in memory gets "lost" or discarded somehow, but why? Which timeout has this effect? How can we change it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a page persistence issue. Have a look at this answer: "[Xpage document is not saved if opened for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529733/785061)"

Comment: That could be the case indeed, although it seems to happen also right after a restart of the server (i.e. when there are no pages in memory). I'll put some pages on _nostate_, that should help a little as well. Tests being continued...