# Why first xpage opened stop responding after open two tabs on browser? In my case i'm opening two different xpages but with same components

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I'm heaving some trouble with xpages. When i open two or more tabs with xpages using the same component, in my case a CustomControl,  the first xpage opened stops responding. I have no clue about this, i'm a beginner with xpages. Is this an issue caused by Dojo? Ps. The custom controls have some viewScope variables shared too. I'm counting on you guys.

Comment: When i say 'tabs' i mean tabs from browser

Comment: It sounds like you are hitting the max number of stored pages. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529733/785061

Comment: It makes sense but a dialog opened inside a XPage count as a page in server memory?

Comment: What does it mean "stop responding". It's a browser. Partial refresh should timeout after while. Please, update your question and add more details.

Comment: My problem is that when navigating through XPages with more than one browser tab opened some errors happens without error in admin console of Domino Administrator and sometimes the page just stop responding and I have to reload the page. If I navigate with just one tab nothing happens, everything goes well. But i dont know why this is happening. I think Henrik Lausten answer is my solution.

Comment: I just noticed errors after doing more tests, but I think Henrik Lausten is right. My server page persistance is set to Keep pages in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Maximum pages in memory" setting. You need to set that to more than the number of tabs open.

What I did was Ah set it manually in the xsp.properties source as e.g. `xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=5`

It solved my problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected yesterday when I linked to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529733/785061

Comment: Lotus Notes 9.0 has this option in Application Properties but in my case I had to set manually.

Comment: I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5.3, I forgot to write that.